# Criteria for Suggesting Tag-Synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, reputation

Could we reconsider the "lower-limit" for allowing users to ***suggest*** Tag-Synonyms?

There are TWO "Reputation Requirements" for ***suggesting*** Tag-Synonyms:

- General Reputation
- Reputation in that Tag.  <-- This is the issue.

Certainly moderating should be reserved for higher reputation, but a requirement for "any reputation" in a Tag's Moderation(?) makes it impossible to ***suggest*** tag-synonyms.

Answer (score -1):

The limit is already too low. The privilege levels for this site are still in "beta" mode, which is a starting point for fledgling sites just getting their feet wet. In all honesty were stuck halfway between being very well established and being too small to be worth SE's time to graduate us.

Developing a taxonomy for the site should be left to those with both a lot of domain expertise and familiarity with the SE system in general. You don't want a constant influx of new ideas to be played out through tug of war. Hence you want a few of the most experienced users to handle those functions.

Site newcomers and even regular long term participants often mistake the function of tags and start treating them like hashtags to spice up posts the way they get used on Twitter and Instagram. That's not what they're for and you want to minimize the lurch that such users can create. Hence creating new tags is also capped to a certain reputation threshold.

Synonyms should clearly be a much higher threshold. Noticing whet existing tag usages start to get conflated requires people paying a lot more attention. Additionally the potential for damage done by flattening tags in the event of a bad synonym is much greater.

If anything, 1250 is too low for this site and we would be better off with the graduated site level of 2500.

Comment: The issue is with the second reputation requirement, not the "General Reputation".  None of these issues raised in this answer actually address the problem.  "Suggesting" tags, and tag-synonyms, is a whole lot different from "Creating" them.  This answer is talking about something completely different than the question.

Comment: @elikakohen The number you are proposing is too high is set at 5. Just 5. That's absurdly low. Such a number basically only checks two things: that the tag exists and that the user has made at least ONE post in that tag, thus suggesting that they might have some clue what it's about. That's a low bar, but it's doing its job. In this case it is stopping you from doing something you shouldn't be doing: proposing synonyms for non existent or just-created tags that shouldn't exist in the first place. If the scenario was such that a synonym was called for you would be able to do it.

Comment: @caleb Just want to note that it isn't 5 rep in a tag, but 5 net up votes on answers, which on small or slow sites can be hard to get. And then at least five people need to have that for a synonym to actually be approved, and even if they exist they are not notified that the synonym is pending. On most sites other than the really big ones it's usually more productive just to ask the mods. I'd support reducing the number of members needed to approve a suggestion.